# SUM возвращает NULL при запросе. Нужно чтобы по умолчанию был 0

Tags: mysql, access, select

Суть проблемы в том, что в Access не срабатывает запрос:

FORMULA:

```
(SELECT Sum(tblPok.PokSumCom) AS [Sum-PokSumCom] FROM tblPok WHERE [Client] = <Client>) + (SELECT Sum(tblCentrPok.PokSumCom) AS [Sum-PokSumCom] FROM tblCentrPok WHERE [Client] = <Client>)
```

Если брать просто `SELECT Sum(tblPok.PokSumCom) AS [Sum-PokSumCom] FROM tblPok WHERE [Client] = <Client>` то все работает для одной таблицы и соответствующего ряда. Соответственно, если же складывать обе суммы (как в начальной формуле) и один из результатов NULL - ничего не работает вообще.

Суть вопроса: как сделать, чтобы при ответе NULL присваивалось автоматические значение 0?
Пробовал различные варианты: `ISNULL(SUM(),0)`, `COALESCE(SUM(),0)` и т.д. Все тщетно.

Есть еще варианты?

Comment: То есть ты пытаешь два набора данных сложить?

Answer (score 1):

Поставить обрамление  select isnull(Sum(tblPok.PokSumCom), 0)

если всёравно нету то так

```
select isnull( (select sum() .... ) , 0)
```

вот полный ответ

```
 select isnull(SELECT Sum(tblPok.PokSumCom) FROM tblPok WHERE [Client] = <Client>), 0) AS [Sum-PokSumCom]
```

Comment: select isnull(SELECT Sum(tblPok.PokSumCom) AS [Sum-PokSumCom] FROM tblPok WHERE [Client] = <Client>), 0)  - так?

Comment: Почти, так тоже можно, алиас в конце, если он нужен (поле будет noname ) 
select isnull(SELECT Sum(tblPok.PokSumCom) FROM tblPok WHERE [Client] = <Client>), 0) AS [Sum-PokSumCom]

Comment: не работает... по логике все ок, но нет и хоть ты тресни

Comment: Может у вас курсор неправильно сконфигурирован? А что дает тогда select 0 ?  А что даёт тогда select isnull( null, 0 ) ? А что даёт select isnull(1,0) ?  0,0,1 ответ? (Проверка может запрос не там записан)

Comment: Я потестирую. Проблема в том, что все это работает через программу, а не в самом access (Программа "Учет клиентов")